# Взять значение из input

Tags: веб-программирование, html, javascript

Подскажите, почему мне никак не получается вывести значение поля val2.

```
    Random value <input type="text" id="val2" name="sum" /><br />
<form name="calcGame" action="">

SELECT<select id='val1' class="filtering" name="persons">
    <option value='0'>Ваш выбор</option>
    <option value='31'>use 100500</option>
    <option value='91'>why not 800</option>
    <option value='181'>i mean 777</option>
</select><br />     </form>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="total">Стоимость игры: 0 рублей</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.forms.calcGame;
        var persons = form.elements.persons;
        var allsum = document.getElementById("sum").value;
        //var sum = form.elements.sum;
        var total = document.querySelector('.total');
        var allsum = getElementById('sum')

persons.onchange = function()
{

    var srok =  total.innerHTML.replace( /\d+/, this.value); //берём значение value 
    //alert(srok);
    if (srok = 31 ){ alert(allsum);
                    //container.innerHTML = 'Вклад срочный';
                }
     else {alert("Алерт не работает")};
    //total.innerHTML = total.innerHTML.replace( /\d+/, this.value * 31);

}
```

Comment: var allsum = document.getElementById("sum").value; - по id нужно искать, а не по name

Comment: Потому что оно там попросту отсутствует!